# How do I uninstall Ubuntu 16.04 running alongside Windows 7 (preferably without using a cd)?

Tags: 16.04, windows, windows-7, uninstall

I was trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my flash drive, but it installed on the computer (at a public library) that I was using (although the computer still runs Windows 7). The librarians asked me to uninstall it because the Ubuntu purple boot menu pops up every time somebody starts the computer. How do I uninstall Ubuntu (preferably without a cd).
This question is not a duplicate because I am asking for instructions when Windows is still on the computer, and I specified that I would rather not use a cd.

Comment: If the library weren't running Windows 7 (indicating they have no real IT support), I'd suggest to them they're better off letting their own knowledgeable people fix it than someone who has already installed on the wrong drive.  As it is, they should be able to use the "Master Boot Record Repair" option on their Windows installation media to remove the GRUB menu, then use tools inside Windows (which should be disabled on a public machine, but probably aren't) to delete the Ubuntu partitions.

Comment: GRUB overwrote the MBR (master boot sector) of the computer's internal hard disk. You can not "repair" this other than by replacing GRUB's code in the MBR with Windows' bootloader again. As there is no backup copy of this code, you need a Windows installation/repair disk to recreate it.

Comment: What specific tools do you mean? I sideclicked computer on the start menu and clicked manage to see If I could find the partition by looking for an extra drive, but I found the normal four drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Byte Commander is saying is that you will need to make a Windows Recovery drive. This will require you to make a bootable USB or DVD/CD. 
Go to `Control Panel > System and Maintenance > Backup and Restore`
Click `Create a system repair disc`. Now boot into the disk, enter your language and keyboard settings. Look near the bottom and click `Repair your computer` and then `Use recovery tools` then click `Command Prompt` then run `bootrec /fixmbr`.

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/17423/windows-7-create-system-repair-disc)